# Query for blank white space before AND after a number string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, whitespace, removing-whitespace

[image]How would i go about constructing a query, that would return all material numbers that have a "blank white space" either BEFORE or AFTER the number string? We are exporting straight from SSMS to excel and we see the problem in the spreadsheet. If i could return all of the material numbers with spaces.. i could go in and edit them or do a replace to fix this issue prior to exporting! (the `mtrl` numbers are imported in via a windows application that users upload an excel template to. This template has all of this data and sometimes they place in spaces in or after the material number). The query we have used to work but now it does not return anything, but upon export we identify these problems you see highlighted in the screenshot (left screenshot) and then query to find that `mtrl` # in the table (right screenshot).  And indeed, it has a space before the 1.

[image]

Currently the query we use looks like:

```
SELECT  Mtrl
FROM dbo.Source
WHERE Mtrl LIKE '% %'
```

Comment: Can you set SSMS to return "Results as text" (I think is the name of the option) and paste a representative text table above?

Comment: Also, I understand you would want to fix the bad data, but you may also `SELECT TRIM(Mtrl) AS Mtrl` to just trim all whitespace from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the data from a query, you should just have that query remove any potential spaces using `LTRIM` and `RTRIM`:

```sql
LTRIM(RTRIM([MTRL]))
```

Keep in mind that these two commands remove *only* spaces, not tabs or returns or other white-space characters.

Doing the above will make sure that the data for the entire set of data is fine, whether or not you find it and/or fix it.

Or, since you are copying-and-pasting from the Results Grid into Excel, you can just `CONVERT` the value to a number which will naturally remove any spaces:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(INT, ' 12 ');
```

Returns:

> 12

So you would just use:

```sql
CONVERT(INT, [MRTL])
```

Now, if you want to find the data that has anything that is not a digit in it, you would use this:

```sql
SELECT Mtrl
FROM   dbo.Source
WHERE  [Mtrl] LIKE '%[^0-9]%'; -- any single non-digit character
```

If the issue is with non-space white-space characters, you can find out which ones they are via the following (to find them at the beginning instead of at the end, change the `RIGHT` to be `LEFT`):

```sql
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT UNICODE(RIGHT([MTRL], 1)) AS [CharVal]
  FROM dbo.Source
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.[CharVal] NOT BETWEEN 48 AND 57 -- digits 0 - 9
AND cte.[CharVal] <> 32; -- space
```

---

And you can fix in one shot using the following, which removes regular spaces (char 32 via `LTRIM`/`RTRIM`), tabs (char 9), and non-breaking spaces (char 160):

```sql
UPDATE src
SET    src.[Mtrl] = REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                    LTRIM(RTRIM(src.[Mtrl])),
                                    CHAR(160),
                                    ''),
                            CHAR(9),
                            '')
FROM   dbo.Source src
WHERE  src.[Mtrl] LIKE '%['    -- find rows with any of the following characters
                          + CHAR(9) -- tab
                          + CHAR(32) -- space
                          + CHAR(160) -- non-breaking space
                          + ']%';
```

Here I used the same WHERE condition that you have since if there can't be any spaces then it doesn't matter if you check both ends or for any at all (and maybe it is faster to have a single LIKE instead of two).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  For some reason i know this should work but the TRIM is not trimming  it upon return.  I have some tinkering to do to find out why.

Comment: @user3896424 Try the CONVERT instead of the LTRIM/RTRIM combination. If it errors, then they aren't spaces but some other type of white-space.

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '101333457 ' to data type int.  <-- error i received...

Comment: Sorry.. i am not a SQL guru.  I inherited this duty from someone who left the company.  We have encountered many strange bugs here and there.

Comment: @user3896424 Well that convert works for me, but probably because whatever character it was shows up as a space in HTML. What version of SQL Server are you using? I will update my answer with a query to find non-space characters.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (2012) 11.0.3000.0

Comment: I have also added the error message.  I was attempting to pull back one mtrl number i know had a space AFTER the string.  and it got that error..Pretty sure its something I did...

Comment: @user3896424 I just updated with a query to find exactly what character is causing the problem. It is not a space as the CONVERT is fine with spaces on either and/or both ends (I have tried it). From the image you just posted, it is taking up two spaces so could be a tab (character value = 9).

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis and hard work! That returned values of 160 (338 rows).

Comment: @user3896424 I have made two updates. I replaced the query to find spaces with one that finds anything that is not a digit. I also changed the UPDATE query to "fix" 3 types of non-digit characters. If you run the update and then run the new "find rows with non-digit characters" and it returns something, run the "cte" query to find what the character value is and hopefully you can see how to update the UPDATE query with an additional `REPLACE` and additional `+ CHAR(xxx)` in the `LIKE`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  So far this is working and i am in the process of running the queries!  I can't thank you enough for your help!